# Get product variation and modify price - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product

I'm looking for a way to target product variations and modify their prices based on the attributes each variation has. The below code is somewhat heading in the right direction, but instead of using product attributes to target variations, I'm relying on matching the variation's current price to a variable in order to target it. It works, but it leaves a ton of room for error with how vague it is.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
function change_price($price, $productd){

if (  $productd->product_type == 'variation' || $productd->product_type == 'variable' ) {

$basicmp3 = 25;

$vprice = get_post_meta( $productd->variation_id, '_regular_price',true);

    if ($vprice == $basicmp3) {

            $vprice2 = $vprice * .5;    
            return $vprice2;
    }
    else{           
         return $vprice;
    } 
}
}
```

**UPDATE** Posted a working solution below

Answer (score 2):

When you run a woocommerce class in a function, there's a need to call some global.

```
 global $woocommerce; $product;
 $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($_POST['variation_id']);
 $regular_price = $product_variation->regular_price;
```

In other Word, it's not because you have `$product` as parameter that you can use the class functions (it's just a 'flatten' object like an array can be). You need to initialize a new object of a class to use $newproductobject->regular_price().

It's possible, if your code is part of a plugin that the woocommerce class are  not yet load, then you'll need to include the file containing the class WC_Product _Variation. (Don't think it's the case)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately your suggestion is giving me a 
_"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No parent product set for variation #0'........"_  message. It goes away if I format it like **$product_variation = $product['variation_id'];** and **$regular_price = $product['regular_price'];**, but all I can manage to return from either string are the numbers 2, 7 and 9, and I'm not sure where those numbers are being pulled from.

Comment: The code was just an example, you can try to get_post_meta to `_variation_id` then `$product_variation= new WC_Product($product_id);  and var_dump the result

Comment: After a little more tweaking I figured out a working solution. Thanks for the head start!

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution. It's probably a little bloated since I'm no code master, but I does it's job! Below is a basic version, but this kind of flexibility will allow for more useful functions, such as automatically bulk discounting variation prices by user role for products who share certain attributes.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
function change_price($price, $productd){


global $post, $woocommerce;
$post_id = $variation->ID;


    $args = array(
                 'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
                 'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
                 'numberposts'   => -1,
                 'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
                 'order'         => 'asc',
                 'post_parent'   => $post->ID
             );
             $variations = get_posts( $args ); 

    //declare variables for later use        
    $demomp3 = '';
    $basicmp3 = '';
    $basicwav = '';
    $premiummp3 = '';
    $premiumwav = '';
    $syncmp3 = '';
    $syncwav = '';

    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

                $variation_id           = absint( $variation->ID );$variable_id = $this['variation_id'];
                $variation_post_status  = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );
                $variation_data         = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
                $variation_data['variation_post_id'] = $variation_id;

                //find attributes
                $option1 = 'pa_license-options';
                $option2 = 'pa_delivery-format';
                $getmeta1 = get_post_meta($variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option1, true);
                $getmeta2 = get_post_meta($variation_id , 'attribute_'.$option2, true);
                $attribute1 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta1, $option1);
                $attribute2 = get_term_by('slug', $getmeta2, $option2);
                $license = $attribute1->name;
                $format = $attribute2->name;


                //get the prices of each variation by the attribute combinations they have              
                if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Demo License" ){

                    //retrieve variation price and assign it to the previously created variable
                    $demomp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }   
                if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Basic License" ){
                    $basicmp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }
                if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Basic License" ){
                    $basicwav = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }   
                if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Premium License" ){
                    $premiummp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }
                if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Premium License" ){
                    $premiumwav = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }   
                if ($format === "mp3" && $license === "Sync License" ){
                    $syncmp3 = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }   
                if ($format === "WAV" && $license === "Sync License" ){
                    $syncwav = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', true ); 

                }   
    }
        //Simple product doesn't need to be modified
        if($productd->product_type == 'simple'){


            return $price;

        }
        //adjust prices of variable products    
        if (  $productd->product_type == 'variation' || $productd->product_type == 'variable' ) {

            $regprice = get_post_meta( $productd->variation_id, '_regular_price',true);
            //target the current variation by matching its price to the one stored in the variable
            if ($regprice == $demomp3) {

                    //apply price adjustment and return the new value
                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else if ($regprice == $basicmp3) {

                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else if ($regprice == $basicwav) {

                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else if ($regprice == $premiummp3) {

                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else if ($regprice == $premiumwav) {

                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else if ($regprice == $syncmp3) {

                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else if ($regprice == $syncwav) {

                    $price = $regprice * .5;    
                    return $price;
            }
            else{           
                 return $price;
            }   
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script to update product variation. click here for detailed explanation.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/bulk-update-product-variation-price-woocommerce/

```
function getExistingProducts($updatedPrices,$skuArray) {

$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), 'posts_per_page' => -1));

while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    $id = get_the_ID();
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    $sku = get_post_meta($id, '_sku', true);

    if( in_array( $sku, $skuArray  ) ) {

        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $attributes['medium-quantity-price']['value'] = $updatedPrices[$sku][4];
        $attributes['low-quantity-price']['value'] = $updatedPrices[$sku][3];
      //  $attributes['v-low-quantity-price']['value'] = $updatedPrices[$sku][2];
        update_post_meta( $id,'_product_attributes',$attributes);
        echo ' Update Sku : '.$sku.' '.PHP_EOL;

    }

endwhile;

}
```